# How to include space in drive label using command-line MS format?

Tags: windows, command-line, format

The obvious-to-me approaches fail.

```
# format h: /fs:ntfs /q /y /V:512MB Disk
Invalid parameter - Disk

# format h: /fs:ntfs /q /y /V:"512MB Disk"
Invalid parameter - Disk"

# format h: /fs:ntfs /q /y /V:"512MB\ Disk"
Invalid parameter - Disk"

# format h: /fs:ntfs /q /y /V:512MB\ Disk
Invalid parameter - Disk
```

Okay, so label works after-the fact.

```
# label h: 512MB Disk

#
```

But how to do it using format?  Am I missing some kind of escape sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the command-line parser used by `format.com` simply does not support quoting of spaces.

The simplest workaround is:

```
format h: /y/q/fs:ntfs/v:foo && label h: My new disk
```